# How to change group names in cumulative incidence plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
cuminc(Surv(dias_hosp_1, hosp_d28_todas_causas) ~ tx_covid, data = m.data1) %>%
    ggcuminc() + 
    labs(
    x = "Days", y = "All-cause 28-day hospitalization"
    ) + 
    add_confidence_interval() +
    add_risktable()+
    add_pvalue()+
```

I got a plot with the names of the groups exactly as coded. Also, the p-value appears outside the plot and I cannot move it inside.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. List all non-base packages/libraries you are using.

Comment: Thanks for reading. Time to event is "dias_hosp_1", event is "hosp_d28_todas_causas", and treatment groups are "tx_covid". There are 3 treatment groups: no treatment, antiviral 1 and antiviral 2. Does this help?